# How to call the Camel Endpoints from Guava Event Bus methods

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Have registered the Guava-Eventbus endpoint in application code like below

```
SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
EventBus eventBus = new EventBus();
registry.put("busName", eventBus);
CamelContext camel = new DefaultCamelContext(registry); 
eventBus.post("Send me to the SEDA queue.");
```

And added the required Camel endpoint into the configure()

```
from("guava-eventbus:busName").to("seda:queue");
```

While running this through Spring Boot application console, Getting the below exception. Can someone help here

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[guava-eventbus:camelTest]] -> [Log[Examp... because of No bean could be found in the registry for: camelTest of type: com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1831) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:136) ~[camel-spring-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:174) ~[camel-spring-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at com.camel.guava.eventbus.App.main(App.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[guava-eventbus:camelTest]] -> [Log[Examp... because of No bean could be found in the registry for: camelTest of type: com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:147) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3932) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3839) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3625) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3477) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:208) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3236) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3232) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3255) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3232) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3155) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:133) ~[camel-spring-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: camelTest of type: com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.mandatoryLookup(CamelContextHelper.java:189) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.guava.eventbus.GuavaEventBusEndpoint.doStart(GuavaEventBusEndpoint.java:135) ~[camel-guava-eventbus-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:75) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:157) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:145) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Also the following exception throws while calling Camel endpoints from @Subscribe method.

`2018-01-19 18:02:25.826 ERROR 4496 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.g.common.eventbus.EventBus.default     : Exception thrown by subscriber method task(java.lang.String) on subscriber com.camel.guava.eventbus.Subscriber@62e118a2 when dispatching event: Testing String
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.camel.guava.eventbus.Subscriber.task(Subscriber.java:16) ~[classes/:na]`

Comment: A good idea can be to look at the unit tests of the component you use and see how its test itself if the doc is lacking